# Python - Checks beginning of a list, until finds the correct item but I showed it which position to start with?

Tags: python, list

```
    AccountU = ['Cam', 'Copper']
    AccountP = ['Pop1234', 'What?']

    def LoginA():
        print ("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=")
        print ("A few clicks away from your selection!")
        UserE = input("Username: ")
        if UserE in AccountU:
            for position, UserE in enumerate(AccountU):
                PasswordF = AccountP[position]
                PassE = input("Password: ")
                if PasswordF == PassE:
                    Menu()
        else:
            print ("Your account is not working.")
            LoginA()
```

In this code, I have tried to make it so that it will enter the username and then find out the position. This should allow it to crosscheck with the password, as they would've been entered at an identical time. However, instead it crosschecks from the beginning until it checks the right location.

For example, if I entered 'Copper' for my username then it would ask the password twice even though I entered 'What?' exactly. I think it could be to do with the 'for position, UserE in enumerate(AccountU):' in particular but I am very confused on what with.

Proof of requiring to enter the password twice.

[image: Proof of requiring to enter the password twice.]

Comment: have you considered using a dictionary to store the usernames and passwords?

Comment: You are overwriting the `UserE` variable every time you loop over the `for` loop. The construct you have written does not fetch the position of the `UserE` (use [`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) for that), it loops over all accounts.

Comment: I know that has nothing to do with your question, but please do never ever store a password in plain text.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to loop over every entry in `AccountU` - you know which username you are looking up, you just want the corresponding password. If you use the `.index()` method you can find the index of the username in the `AccountU` list. Then, assuming `AccountP` is directly matched to `AccountU` you can find the correct password at the same index, like so:

```
AccountU = ['Cam', 'Copper']
AccountP = ['Pop1234', 'What?']

def LoginA():
    print ("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=")
    print ("A few clicks away from your selection!")
    UserE = input("Username: ")
    if UserE in AccountU:
        PasswordF = AccountP[AccountU.index(UserE)]
        PassE = input("Password: ")
        if PasswordF == PassE:
            Menu()
        else:
            print ("Incorrect Password")
    else:
        print ("Your account is not working.")
        LoginA()
```

However, you would be better using a dictionary to store your usernames and passwords. This will ensure that the correct user is matched up to the correct password. Here's an example of how that might work:

```
accounts = {'Cam': 'Pop1234',
            'Copper': 'What?'}

def LoginA():
    print ("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=")
    print ("A few clicks away from your selection!")
    UserE = input("Username: ")
    if UserE in accounts.keys():
        PassE = input("Password: ")
        if accounts[UserE] == PassE:
            Menu()
        else:
            print ("Incorrect Password")
    else:
        print ("Your account is not working.")
        LoginA()
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with

```
           for position, UserE in enumerate(AccountU):
                PasswordF = AccountP[position]
```

1. you are overwriting UserE
2. Your are asking password for every user.

Make if condition and check password for user entered.

```
           for position, User in enumerate(AccountU):
                if UserE == User:
                    PasswordF = AccountP[position]
                    .... your code ......
```

Using Dictionary is better choice.